# How to make fixed size div regardless of content

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The following code display an image and title:

```
  <div id="eventsCollapse" class="panel-collapse collapse" ng-controller="videoController">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="video in eventVideoDetails | filter:{category:'events'} | orderBy:'videoData.data.title'">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img ng-src="{{video.videoData.data.thumbnail.hqDefault}}"/>
            <p>{{video.videoData.data.title}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Which looks like the following:

[image: screen shot of code result]

The title of the video in the first thumbnail overflows onto the next line. This causes the size of the thumbnail to increase, which throws off the grid style I was going for.

Can somebody point me in the right direction for a better approach / CSS solution?

Comment: Can you post your code for multiple thumbnails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `css`:

```
.thumbnail p {
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 14px;
height: 14px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

will prevent text (sized at `12px`, with a line-height of `14px`) from overflowing onto a second line.

In the styles above, if you adjust the `font-size:` and `line-height:` and `height:` to suit, your `.thumbnail p` should then always display as a single line. Whenever the line is too long for the space available, the line will be truncated with `...` added immediately after the truncation.